# How to add pages of images to horizontalscrollview android?

Tags: android, web-services, gridview, horizontalscrollview

I need a help in doing a task in my app. I want to load images in gridview from server. On swiping left the next set of images has to be loaded in the gridview. On swiping right again it has to show the previous set of images which is already loaded in the gridview. On clicking one image in gridview it has to show the details of that image. Please help me if anybody knows.

Comment: Instead of using horizontal scrollview, maybe use viewPager and for the content view create a gridview layout.. this is a little complicated as it would probably require two adapters or at least an array of arrays..

Comment: can u give me an example? or sample project link?